# Format a number to display in thousands or millions without dividing

Tags: .net, formatting

Is there a custom number format string that can be used to display a number as thousands or millions?

e.g. I would like to display the number 2,234,567.00 as:

$2,235 (if in thousands)

...or...

$2.2 (if in millions)

...using different FormatStrings in:

```
    MsgBox(MyNumber.ToString("FormatStrings"))
```

I'd prefer never to have to build logic that divides numbers by 1,000 or 1,000,000 based on the desired display string.

Comment: Best bet is to define your own IFormatter instance that can handle this.

Comment: @Igor, Seems odd that there isn't innate capability already there, considering that percent formats multiply by 100, for example.

Comment: Everything that is available out of the box can be found here: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Igor, Thanks - I saw that.  I was hoping someone had figured out how to do this using custom format strings, not standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the group separator "," for scaling as described in [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierTh).

E.g.

```
double d = 2234567.00;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("#,0,")); // 2,235
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("#,0,.0")); // 2,234.6
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("#,0,,.0")); //2.2
```

Comment: That's perfect, @Joe.

Answer (score -1):

@Joe's answer is correct - the following just provides additional context and the answer is presented in the same format as the question.

It's actually straightforward.

To show 2,234,567.00 - in thousands - as 2,235...

```
    MsgBox(MyNumber.ToString("#,##0,"))
```

To show 2,234,567.00 - in millions - as 2.2...

```
    MsgBox(MyNumber.ToString("#,##0,,.0"))
```

The magic happens with those commas after the 0.  They each replace three digits.